# Decoding Permutated English Strings

Tags: algorithm, puzzle, nlp

A coworker was recently asked this when trying to land a (different) research job:

Given 10 128-character strings which have been permutated in exactly the same way, decode the strings. The original strings are English text with spaces, numbers, punctuation and other non-alpha characters removed.

He was given a few days to think about it before an answer was expected. How would you do this? You can use any computer resource, including character/word level language models.

Comment: Vote to close: This is "not constructive" - there is no way this can be answered in a definitive manner.  At best, people can make suggestions.

Comment: sorry about the edit.  i changed then title then realised it was just "english english" so reverted, but am still listed as an editor.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I guess I should add that I tried tried to help him out and neither of us could come up with anything that was computationally feasable. This question has been bothering me for a while and I'd like to see if there's a good way to solve it.

Comment: You haven't defined the permutation types.  Does this mean that it was at a character level, and the same permutation was applied to each character, in place?  Or do you mean that the letters were retained, but locations were permuted?

Comment: @Iterator: the locations are permutated.

Comment: @NateGlenn: Did you find any optimized method to solve this problem?

Comment: @Paniz Nope, sorry. I do like Iterator's advice, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a basic [transposition cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher).  My question above was simply to determine if it was a transposition cipher or a substitution cipher.  Cryptanalysis of such systems is fairly straightforward.  Others have already alluded to basic methods.  Optimal approaches will attempt to place the hardest and rarest letters first, as these will tend to uniquely identify the letters around them, which greatly reduces the subsequent search space.  Simply finding *a* place to place an "a" (no pun intended) is not hard, but finding a location for a "q", "z", or "x" is a bit more work.

The overarching goal for an algorithm's quality isn't to decipher the text, as it can be done by better than brute force methods, nor is it simply to be fast, but it should eliminate possibilities *absolutely as fast as possible*.

Since you can use multiple strings simultaneously, attempting to create words from the rarest characters is going to allow you to test dictionary attacks in parallel.  Finding the correct placement of the rarest terms in each string as quickly as possible will decipher that ciphertext PLUS all of the others at the same time.

If you search for cryptanalysis of transposition ciphers, you'll find a bunch with genetic algorithms. These are meant to advance the research cred of people working in GA, as these are not really optimal in practice.  Instead, you should look at some basic optimizatin methods, such as branch and bound, A*, and a variety of statistical methods. (How deep you should go depends on your level of expertise in algorithms and statistics. :)  I would switch between deterministic methods and statistical optimization methods several times.)

In any case, the calculations should be *dirt cheap* and fast, because the scale of initial guesses could be quite large.  It's best to have a cheap way to filter out a LOT of possible placements first, then spend more CPU time on sifting through the better candidates.  To that end, it's good to have a way of describing the stages of processing and the computational effort for each stage.  (At least that's what I would expect if I gave this as an interview question.)

You can even [buy a fairly credible reference book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0894122541) on deciphering double transposition ciphers.

---

Update 1: Take a look at [these slides](http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/hillclimb02.pdf) for more ideas on iterative improvements.  It's not a great reference set of slides, but it's readily accessible.  What's more, although the slides are about GA and simulated annealing (methods that come up a lot in search results for transposition cipher cryptanalysis), the author advocates against such methods when you can use A* or other methods.  :)

Comment: R u still agree with this method and think this is the most optimized way? I want to implement it, if you have any other idea I'll appreciate to share here.

Answer (score 1):

first, you'd need a test for the correct ordering.  something fairly simple like being able to break the majority of texts into words using a dictionary ordered by frequency of use without backtracking.

one you have that, you can play with various approaches.  two i would try are:

- using a genetic algorithm, with scoring based on 2 and 3-letter tuples (which you can either get from somewhere or generate yourself).  the hard part of genetic algorithms is finding a good description of the process that can be fragmented and recomposed.  i would guess that something like "move fragment x to after fragment y" would be a good approach, where the indices are positions in the original text (and so change as the "dna" is read).  also, you might need to extend the scoring with something that gets you closer to "real" text near the end - something like the length over which the verification algorithm runs, or complete words found.
- using a graph approach.  you would need to find a consistent path through the graph of letter positions, perhaps with a beam-width search, using the weights obtained from the pair frequencies.  i'm not sure how you'd handle reaching the end of the string and restarting, though.  perhaps 10 sentences is sufficient to identify with strong probability good starting candidates (from letter frequency) - wouldn't surprise me.

this is a nice problem :o)  i suspect 10 sentences is a strong constraint (for every step you have a good chance of common letter pairs in several strings - you probably want to combine probabilities by discarding the most unlikely, unless you include word start/end pairs) so i think the graph approach would be most efficient.

Comment: Do u still agree with your method? I want to solve this problem as a small project, which solution suggested in this topic do you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

First you need a scoring function that increases as the likelihood of a correct permutation increases. One approach is to precalculate the frequencies of triplets in standard English (get some data from Project Gutenburg) and add up the frequencies of all the triplets in all ten strings. You may find that quadruplets give a better outcome than triplets.

Second you need a way to produce permutations. One approach, known as hill-climbing, takes the ten strings and enters a loop. Pick two random integers from 1 to 128 and swap the associated letters in all ten strings. Compute the score of the new permutation and compare it to the old permutation. If the new permutation is an improvement, keep it and loop, otherwise keep the old permutation and loop. Stop when the number of improvements slows below some predetermined threshold. Present the outcome to the user, who may accept it as given, accept it and make changes manually, or reject it, in which case you start again from the original set of strings at a different point in the random number generator.

Instead of hill-climbing, you might try simulated annealing. I'll refer you to Google for details, but the idea is that instead of always keeping the better of the two permutations, sometimes you keep the lesser of the two permutations, in the hope that it leads to a better overall outcome. This is done to defeat the tendency of hill-climbing to get stuck at a local maximum in the search space.

By the way, it's "permuted" rather than "permutated."

Comment: Do u still agree with your method? I want to solve this problem as a small project, which solution suggested in this topic do you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

[Frequency analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis_%28cryptanalysis%29) would drastically prune the search space.  The most-common letters in English prose are [well-known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aEnglish_letter_frequency_%28alphabetic%29.svg).

Count the letters in your encrypted input, and put them in most-common order.  Matching most-counted to most-counted, translated the cypher text back into an attempted plain text.  It will be close to right, but likely not exactly.  By hand, iteratively tune your permutation until plain text emerges (typically few iterations are needed.)

If you find checking by hand odious, run attempted plain texts through a spell checker and minimize violation counts.

Comment: Do u still agree with your method? I want to solve this problem as a small project, which solution suggested in this topic do you prefer?